how to create and return a dataframe in a function?
I have a function pmi_count_phrase_create() where I input 2 lists want to return a dataframe composed of the lists I create in the function. Problem right now is I am getting a tuple containing the three lists instead.
This is my code:
def pmi_count_phrase_create(pmi_tups,freq_list):
    import pandas as pd

    """pmi_tups is result of running pmi_tups = [i for i in finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.pmi)] 
       freq_list is a result of running freq_list= finder.ngram_fd.items()
       
       -> 1 df made up of columns for  pmi list, count list, phrase list"""
    pmi3_list =[]
    count3_list =[]
    phrase3_list =[]
    for phrase, pmi in pmi_tups:
        for item in freq_list:
            quadgram,count = item
            if quadgram == phrase:
                pmi3_list.append(pmi)
                count3_list.append(count)
                phrase3_list.append(phrase)

                # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Phrase':phrase3_list,'PMI':pmi3_list,'Count':count3_list})
    return df

and my current output is a tuple of the form: (pmi3_list,count3_list,phrase3_list)
What I want is a dataframe:
    Phrase                       PMI    Count
0   (activated, charcoal)     15.213655 12
1   (vocal, cords)            14.950620 10
2   (fossil, fuels)           14.872618 15
3   (simplified, explanation) 14.669334 12
4   (midnight, weekend)   14.181233 11


There's no way this could be returning a tuple. return df is the correct way to return the dataframe.

You would get the result you describe if the function ended with return pmi3_list,count3_list,phrase3_list

Are you sure this is the version of the code you're running?

yes! This is my code:
bigram_pmi = [i for i in finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.pmi)]    bigram_freq1 = finder.ngram_fd.items()                                                                   pmi_count_phrase_create(bigram_pmi,bigram_freq1)

and my function in the question is exactly the same as the one I am running

I agree with Barmar. This doesn't make sense and it sounds like you're running the wrong script by accident. Make a [mre].

You're not assigning the result of the function call to anything.

Thanks ! That's what was missing !Works now...

Perhaps try:
def pmi_count_phrase_create(pmi_tups,freq_list):
    import pandas as pd

    """pmi_tups is result of running pmi_tups = [i for i in 
finder.score_ngrams(bigram_measures.pmi)] 
   freq_list is a result of running freq_list= finder.ngram_fd.items()
   
   -> 1 df made up of columns for  pmi list, count list, phrase list"""
    pmi3_list =[]
    count3_list =[]
    phrase3_list =[]
    for phrase, pmi in pmi_tups:
        for item in freq_list:
            quadgram,count = item
            if quadgram == phrase:
                pmi3_list.append(pmi)
                count3_list.append(count)
                phrase3_list.append(phrase)

            # create dataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Phrase':phrase3_list,'PMI':pmi3_list,'Count':count3_list})
    return df

Where you use pd.Dataframe.from_dict instead of pd.Dataframe.

pd.DataFrame() automatically does this if the argument is a dict. It certainly won't  return a tuple.
